# Storing analog signal from sensor on COM Port into Java

Tags: serial-port, signals, android-sensors, data-acquisition

i am working on a drowsiness detection project using ECG signals,i am still a newbie in Java programming, i have a sensor that i have tweaked to send ECG signals on the COM port of my laptop, can i in Java acquire that signal and save it as a file on my laptop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the operating system? Can you connect to your sensor using MobaXTerm or similar terminal app?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1